# Win32, WinMain vs custom Entry Point (huge size difference), why?

Tags: c, winapi

As topic says.

I noticed that if i use WinMain or any other default Entry Point, a C application can be like 70kb.

But if i just specify a custom Entry Point, say "RawMain", int RawMain().
Then the file will be like 6kb.

So i am wondering, why is this, what does it add/reference to the file?
I could understand there being some small difference in size, but the difference is huge for an empty application.

Thanks!

Comment: What source are you building, and what are your build instructions?

Comment: Well my own source, but basically just a simple Win32 Window i think suffice for this.
So a Window Handle, MessageLoop etc.
I May be wrong i haven't tests in depth, but i would have thought there to be easy to tell what causes the size difference. Cause i can only assume much stuff is being referenced and implemented in the file (even on Release build mode). Which means it's Used (not by me personally) somewhere.

Worth noting is this is with Static Library. So i am guessing WinMain forces much of the CRL to be added or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building for windows in most environments, the actual program entry point will be provided by a function in a small runtime library.  That will do some environment preparation and then call a function you provide, such as main, wmain, WinMain, etc.

The code that runs before your user-provided main function includes running global C++ constructors, enabling TLS variables, initializing global mutexes so that standard-library calls work properly in a multithreaded environment, setting up the standard locale, and other stuff.

One thing that setting the entry point does is starts the linker with an undefined symbol with the name you give the entry point, so for example, if you're using mingw32, the linker will start assuming that it needs to link `libmingw32.a` and with the undefined symbol `__tmainCRTStartup`.

The linker will find (hopefully) `__tmainCRTStartup` in `libmingw32.a`, and include the object file `crtexe.o` which contains it, along with anything else needed to satisfy undefined symbols emanating from `crtexe.o`, which is where the extra size comes from.

When you set your own entry point, you override this, and just set the linker to look for whatever function you specify.  You get a smaller executable, but you have to be careful that features you're using don't rely on any of the global initialization that would be done by the runtime's startup function.

Comment: Could you give any examples on what i should be careful about?
Cause the input parameters like HInstance etc can be gotten elsewhere.
But i am guessing you are talking about other stuff.

(Could be useful to know so i don't walk on any land mines).
And also, when using your own entry point, are you supposed to use ExitProcess as it seems the application won't close itself completely.

Comment: Using standard C locale functions, assuming that globals defined in thread local storage point to meaningful values, use of strtok from the standard C library in a multithreaded environment.  Those are the ones I can think of that affect C on windows.

Comment: @Zerowalker: There are lots more features the CRT is responsible for. In addition, the CRT initializes the FPU environment, implements part of the SEH exception handling, and contains code for multi-word arithmetic. This list is still not exhaustive, but it should be clear, that (while possible) it is a real challenge to write an application, that doesn't use the CRT. Some of the features will fail with compiler/linker errors, but others (e.g. running initializers for global objects) are silently skipped.